# How can I calculate the Expected time to roll two dice and get all 1 through 36 combinations?

Tags: probability, coupon-collector

If I have two dice and I want to check the expected time it takes for all combinations to appear once, how can I calculate that? I am aware of the calculations for one die using geometric distribution, but how can I calculate with two dice?

Comment: Could you do it if you had one 36-sided die?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Would $(3,4)$ be the same combination as $(4,3)$?

Comment: With a single die, the expected number of trials is $6(\frac11+\frac12+\dots+\frac16)$. Analogously, for two die, the expected number of rolls is $36(\frac11+\frac12+\dots+\frac1{36})$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  yes I can do that. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @MichaelHoppe No, (3,4) and (4,3) will be different combinations

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thank you for the clarification and solution.

Comment: I removed the [tag:geometric-probability] and [tag:probability-theory] tags – please read the tag summary when using a tag.

Answer (score 1):

There are $36$ combinations, each is equally likely. You can do this the same way you calculate it for "one 36-sided die".

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.